# Run code in UITableViewCell Swift when the Main View or Cell is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The problem I'm having is with triggering code as soon as a cell is displayed on screen.

What I have is grouped cells, much like in the settings application for iOS, with one segueing to a view with a date picker. After closing that view, i save the selected date, but I want to be able to fire my code so I can display the date in the detail text of a cell.

The cell that I want to display the date in has a swift file attached to it, as a UITableViewCell subclass/class.

I need a method similar to the `viewDidLoad()` on normal UIViewControllers where I can run code as soon as it appears on screen.

Something like this:

```
when cell comes on screen {
    runCode()
}
```

I've tried with awakeFromNib, but with my understanding it only happens when the view is loaded from a previous view, not when it is transitioned back from a segue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to refresh the contents of the cell, not looking for something similar to viewDidLoad().

What you'll want to do is after a user selects a date, you call the `reloadData()` on your tableview or to be more efficient, `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;` with the updated cell's indexPath.